# Split values in dataframe into separate dataframe column -spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My requirement is to convert the below dataframe

`df.show()`

```
Id | vals
1  | name=John || age=25 || col1 =val1  || col2= val2
2  | name=Joe  || age=23 || col1 =val11 || col2= val22
```

Into

```
Id | name | age |  col1 | col2
1  | John |  25 |  val1 | val2
2  | Joe  |  23 | val11 |val22
```

Please assist me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use spark sql split function to split your string and convert to array[string] and then select the columns accordingly. Something like below:

```
 val df1 = df.withColumn("vals",split($"vals","\\|\\|"))
           .select($"id",split($"vals"(0),"=")(1).alias("name"),
            split($"vals"(1),"=")(1).alias("age"),
            split($"vals"(2),"=")(1).alias("col1"),
            split($"vals"(3),"=")(1).alias("col2"))
```

Comment: Thanks wypul for your quick response. Is it possible to get the column names as well instead of hardcoding it

Answer (score 2):

To generate the wanted result in a dynamic fashion, here's one approach that uses a mix of `split` and `explode` to transform column `vals` into an `ArrayType` column of `[key, value]` (e.g. ["name", "john"]), followed by a grouping by `id` and `pivot` on the `key` to aggregate `value`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "name=John || age=25 || col1 =val1  || col2= val2"),
  (2, "name=Joe  || age=23 || col1 =val11 || col2= val22")
).toDF("id", "vals")

df.
  withColumn("flattened", explode(split($"vals", "\\s*\\|\\|\\s*"))).
  withColumn("kv_array", split($"flattened", "\\s*=\\s*")).
  groupBy($"id").pivot($"kv_array"(0)).agg(first($"kv_array"(1))).
  show
// +---+---+-----+-----+----+
// |id |age|col1 |col2 |name|
// +---+---+-----+-----+----+
// |1  |25 |val1 |val2 |John|
// |2  |23 |val11|val22|Joe |
// +---+---+-----+-----+----+
```